# Measurable set and continuous function exercise

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a measurable set. Show that $f:\mathbb R_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb R$, given by $f(r)=|E \cap B(0,r)|$ is continuous.

So, given a fixed $r_0 \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ and given $\epsilon$, I want to prove there is $\delta>0 : |r_0-x|<\delta \implies |f(r_0)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. We have $$|f(r_0)-f(x)|=||E \cap B(0,r_0)|_e-|E \cap B(0,x)|_e|$$

Since $|E \cap B(0,r)|_e \leq |B(0,r)|_e < \infty$ for any $r$, then $$||E \cap B(0,r_0)|_e-|E \cap B(0,x)|_e| \leq |E \cap B(0,r_0) \triangle E \cap B(0,x_0)|_e$$

Here I got stuck, I still didn't use the fact that $E$ is measurable. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does $|E|$ denote the measure of $E$? If so, you need $E$ to be measurable to be able to consider $f$. (If $E$ is not measurable, then $E\cup B(0,r)$ is not necessarily measurable, so $f$ may be undefined for some $r$)

Comment: @user3493525 The first thing the problem says is that $E$ is measurable.

Comment: @Nathanson I know. I tried to clear up the fact that the OP did actually use the fact that $E$ is measurable.

Comment: @user3493525 Your selected answer wouldn't work if you happen to consider other measures than the Lebesgue measure (or measures absolutely continuous with respect to it). It also wouldn't work if the filtering sets $B(0,x)$ were not balls. On the other hand, the result is still true if those changes are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s \in \Bbb R_{\ge 0}$. For all $r > s$,

$$0 \le f(r) - f(s) = |E\cap [B(0,r)\setminus B(0,s)]| \le |B(0,r) \setminus B(0,s)| = C_n(r^n - s^n),$$

where $C_n$ is a constant depending only on $n$. Since $r^n - s^n \to 0$ as $r \to s$, it follows that $f(r) \to f(s)$ as $r\to s^{+}$. A similar argument shows that $f(r) \to f(s)$ as $r\to s^{-}$. Hence $f$ is continuous at $s$. Since $s$ was arbitrary, $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious but I couldn't follow why $|B(0,r) \setminus B(0,s)| \le C_n(r^n - s^n)$, where $C_n$ comes from? And why is it $r^n$ and $s^n$ and not just $r$ and $s$? I've tried to make a picture of one ball inside the other but I still can't figure out analytically which is the maximum distance between two points of each ball.

Comment: Since $B(0,r)\setminus B(0,s)$ is the set of all points $x\in \Bbb R^n$ for which $|s| \le |x| < r$, it's measure is (using spherical coordinates) $\int_s^r \int_{S^{n-1}} \rho^{n-1}\, d\omega\, d\rho = C_n(r^n - s^n)$, where $C_n = |S^{n-1}|/n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r_n\to r$ be increasing. Latter we need to do the case of decreasing.

Then $|f(r)-f(r_n)|\\=m(E\cap B_r)-m(E\cap B_{r_n})\\=m(E\cap\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}(B_{r_{k+1}}-B_{r_k}))\\=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}m(E\cap(B_{r_{k+1}}-B_{r_k}))\to0$

The last limit is because $\sum_{k=-1}^{\infty}m(E\cap(B_{r_{k+1}}-B_{r_k}))$ is convergent, it is equal to $m(E\cap B_r)$ by $\sigma$-additivity, where we write $B_{-1}=\emptyset$.

Do, the analogous thing for decreasing $r_n\to r$. You will need to use that $m(E\cap B_{r_1})\leq m(B_{r_1})$ is finite.